# How to make Observable.flatMap to wait to resolve

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ava

Playing with RxJS and React, I'm having problem of how to wait for data in Observable.fromPromise generated within map on another Observable.

I have async helper:

```
const dataStreamGenerator = (url = CLIENTS_DATA_URL) => (
  Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch(url))
  .flatMap(response => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(response.json()))
  .catch(err => Rx.Observable.of(new Error(err)))
);
```

Then I have `actions.fetchClients$` which is `Rx.Subject`:

```
actions.fetchClients$.map((url = CLIENTS_DATA_URL) => {
    const ts = Date.now();
    console.log('FETCH CLIENTS with: ', url);
    return dataStreamGenerator(url);
  }).map(val => {
    console.log('GOT DATA IN REDUCER: ', val);
    const error = (val instanceof Error) ? val.message : undefined;
    const data = error ? undefined : val;
    actions.receivedClientsData$.next({ data, error, ts: Date.now() });
    return (state) => state;
  })
```

(Yes, trying to mimick Redux in RxJS).

Whan I test the `dataStreamGenerator`, it works ok (with `ava`) and delivers data:

```
test('dataStreamGenerator', t => {
  const ds$ = dataStreamGenerator(CLIENTS_DATA_URL);
  return ds$.do((data) => {
    t.is(data.length, 10);
  });
});
```

(AVA automatically subscribe to observable and consume it, so there is no need to subscribe).

But the `actions.fetchClients$.map((url = CLI...` second map (starting... `console.log('GOT DATA IN REDUCER: ', val);...` is still getting the Observable and not the data from dataStream$.

I tried all possible combinations of `map` and `flatMap` in fetchClients$ code but still no luck.

My test code is:

```
test.only('fetchClients$', t => {
  const initialState = {};
  actions.fetchClients$.next('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  reducer$.subscribe(val => {
    console.log('TEST SUBSCRIBE VAL: ', val);
    t.pass();
  });
  actions.fetchClients$.next('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
});
```

I cant figure out how to wait to the Observable `dataStreamGenerator(url);` to emit data and not the Observable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flatten the results of what you returned from `dataStreamGenerator`.

```
actions.fetchClients$
  //This is now a flatMap
  .flatMap((url = CLIENTS_DATA_URL) => {
    const ts = Date.now();
    console.log('FETCH CLIENTS with: ', url);
    return dataStreamGenerator(url);
  });
```

The `map` operator delivers the value *as-is* down stream, whereas `flatMap` will flatten `Observables`, `Arrays` and `Promises` such that their values are what get propagated.

It works in the test case because you are directly subscribing to the `Observable` returned by `dataStreamGenerator`.

Comment: Thanks @paulpdaniels. I tried even this before but was puzzled by the test output. It seems that the whole problem is with ava - not waiting for fetch being resolved and finishing early (after first value delivered). I should add `ava` to tags.